# ERROR Error: this.validator is not a function

Tags: angular

I get this error after creating FormGroup.

[image: image of the error]

I created a simple error template on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-example-this-validator-is-not-a-function?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

My sample data is as follows:

[image]

Create a FormGroup as shown below:

[image]

I understand that it is not possible to create FormGroup of a string array. Because the data does not have a key value to create a name for the form group.

Is there a way to deal with this?

Comment: You can use a formArray for this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tranform arr_obj and arr_str into formArray using map operator something like this:

```
   const formConfig = this.data.map((item)=>{
      if(item.arr_obj || item.arr_str){
        return {...item,arr_obj: this.fb.group(item.arr_obj),arr_str: this.fb.array(item.arr_str)}
      } 
      return item;
    });

    formConfig.forEach(item => {
      var temp = this.fb.group(item);
      console.log(temp);
    });
```